# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'setAttribute' of undefined or null reference jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I'm getting following error only when try to execute the mvc 4 application via IE 11 but it works fine with google chrome.

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'setAttribute' of undefined or null reference jquery

Following is the piece of code where the error occurs. But I can ensure there is no datapicker object on the login screen. What must be causing the problem?

```
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
$(function () {
    $("input[type='date']")
                .datepicker()
                .get(0)
                .setAttribute("type", "text");
})
```

}

Comment: Why are you calling `document ready` inside `if` statement? And the second one: use this one `$("input[type='date']").attr("type", "text")` or `$("input[type='date']").prop("type", "text")`

Comment: Also, just checked your code in jsfiddle and it works fine (without `if` statement because I don't have Modernizr object defined).

Comment: adding prop or attr didn't make any difference apart from below message :0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'prop' of undefined or null reference

Comment: If is used because I wanted to use HTML5 date picker instead of jquery whenever it's available.

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute with `.attr()`. The link to the [API](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)